# p2.js bodies moving through other

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a tree in js. I draw it on canvas.
I'm using p2.js physics engine for branches' realistic moving. I'm joining branches by RevoluteConstraint.
I have one problem. My branches jam between themselves.

All worked. But I want that brenches' bodies will be absolute and can move through other brenches.

I tried to set tolerance of world's solver to high, or low, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
world = new p2.World({
    gravity: [0, 10]
});

//new branch (fromX, fromY - from prev branch)
var body = new p2.Body({
    mass: 0,
    angle: this._generateAngle(-45, 45)
});
body.position[0] = fromX-(Math.sin(body.angle))*shape.height/2;
body.position[1] = fromY-(-Math.cos(body.angle))*shape.height/2;
body.addShape(new p2.Rectange(0.3, Math.random()*2));

//joining prev branch and this branch
var rc = new p2.RevoluteConstraint(prev_branch, body, {
    localPivotA: [0, -prev_branch.shapes[0].height/2],
    localPivotB: [0, body.shapes[0].height/2]
});
rc.setLimits(-Math.PI/8, Math.PI/8);
world.addConstraint(rc);
world.addBody(body);
```

Full code: http://dkaraush.shpp.me/tree.js

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to disable all collisions in your scene. This is done by turning off collision response on all bodies:

```
// Turns off collisions with this body
body.collisionResponse = false;
```

If you want to disable collisions between branches, but still enable collisions with other things in your scene, you need to use collision groups and masks.

To do this, we create two collision groups, one for scenery shapes and one for branch shapes. When creating the shapes in the scene, we tell them what group they belongs to (.collisionGroup) and what group(s) they can collide with (.collisionMask).

Example:

```
// Create collision groups
var SCENERY_GROUP = 1;
var BRANCH_GROUP = 2;

// Branch shape
branchShape.collisionGroup = BRANCH_GROUP; // Set group for this branch.
branchShape.collisionMask = SCENERY_GROUP; // It can only collide with scenery.

// Ground shape
groundShape.collisionGroup = SCENERY_GROUP; // Set group for the ground.
groundShape.collisionMask = BRANCH_GROUP; // It can only collide with branches.
```

If you want to see this p2.js feature in action, have a look at the [Ragdoll demo](https://schteppe.github.io/p2.js/demos/ragdoll.html).